# How could i replace negative values in this column to 0

Tags: sql-server

```
SUM([X Limited$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry].[Amount (LCY)]) AS DAmount
```

how can i replace negative values with 0 in this column i tried

```
select sUM(IF ([X Limited$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry].[Amount (LCY)]  < 0, 0, X Limited$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry].[Amount (LCY)] )) as DAmount
```

Comment: which database you are using actually?

Comment: So you've got two [tag:mysql] tags and one [tag:sql-server] tag. These are *different* products. Pick one, then edit your question and remove the *inappropriate* tags.

Answer (score 1):

You could use case when

```
select sum(case when [X Limited$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry].[Amount (LCY)] >0 
  then [X Limited$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry].[Amount (LCY)]  end ) as DAmount
```

Comment: @Strawberry - if you think simpler solutions are available, why not add an answer with one rather than making someone else's answer vague?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression:

```
(CASE WHEN SUM([X Limited$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry].[Amount (LCY)]) > 0
      THEN SUM([X Limited$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry].[Amount (LCY)])
      ELSE 0
 END) AS DAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
select case when SUM([X Limited$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry].[Amount (LCY)])<0 then 0 else SUM([X Limited$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry].[Amount (LCY)]) end
  AS DAmount
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Zaynul Abadin Tuhi

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed there are multiple answers with case statements but there is another option which might interest you (using a where clause).

```
Select SUM([X Limited$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry].[Amount (LCY)]) AS DAmount
FROM Table
Where [X Limited$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry].[Amount (LCY)]>0
```